Brisk walk routine
I've devised a brisk walking routine around my work and would welcome views on its effectiveness. Please note, this is the best that suits available time.

Morning > leave home 7:00am > walk to train station > 1.1Km in 12min approx
Morning > get off the train by 8:15am > walk to office > 1.5Km in 13-15min approx.
Afternoon > lunch break 12:30pm > walk around office > 3Km in 25-27min approx.
Evening > finish work 5:00pm > walk to train station > 1.5Km in 13-15min approx.
Evening > get off the train by 6:30pm > walk home > 1.1Km in 12min approx.

I follow the above from Mon-Fri.
Age: 44
Goal: healthy body and healthy mind
Fitness level: no official data.
Body fat: no recorded data
Weight: 75Kg
Thoughts, comments, suggestions? Thanks.

Effectiveness for what goal? What kind of answer are you looking for? Also how old are you, fitness level, body fat level... Can you [edit] your question to add more details?

Would have to state u're height to know if 75 is fat or thin

Integrating active routines through your normal days is the best way to achieve long term health improvement, because it's easiest to stay consitent and do them almost every day. Good Job on trying to better your fitness & health and coming up with this plan! Also integrating it into everyday life will give you more time for other things.

You are walking about 75 minutes per day, 5 days per week.  If you do nothing else, this will greatly improve your health.  Primarily, this pattern of walking will reduce your risk of some major health issues, such as heart disease and stroke. It should also help manage your weight and body composition and this distributed pattern should provide mental breaks that will reduce stress and contribute to better mental health.
Your current routine focuses on your cardio-vascular system and the muscles in your legs.  One thing I would recommend is adding some resistance training and flexibility.  For example, you could do some stretching when you get home from work.  The muscles in your legs will already be warmed up from your walk and with a few more minutes to loosen up the rest of your body, a 15-minute stretch would be beneficial.
Adding some resistance training will help to increase your bone mineral density and help you maintain muscle as you get older.  Push-ups are a great strengthening exercise that don't require any equipment or a gym membership.  This is a strength workout that you could do at home with nothing more than a wall and a chair.
As a runner, I got into a rut of just running.  While running is an excellent form of exercise, I later adopted a more balanced approach to fitness that has served me even better.  I think you're going in the right direction.  Adding some strength and flexibility training to your walking routine will round things out nicely.

It's much, much better for you to have one unbroken aerobic session of 75 minutes, than, separate parts.
Just use cars and taxis to and from work, and the moment you get home, pull on your shorts and Tevas and take one unbroken non-stope walk of minimum. 60 mins.
